# Convergence diagnostic with Gelman-Rubin PSRF: R coda package vs Runjags

Tags: r, bayesian, mcmc, convergence, runjags

I run Bayesian models with Runjags and then convert the output in MCMC.list with the coda package. I check convergence with the Gelman-Rubin diagnostic (univariate).

Sometimes, the PSRF is large just because a chain sampled a large value at some point (PsRF goes from ~1 to 1,2). On the other side, the PSRF is close to 1 with Runjags. Sometimes Runjags has larger PSRF than Coda.

I didn't find what is the difference in calculation. Do you know it?
Is-it ok to think that the parameter converged from plots even if the PSRF is 1,2?

Comment: Generally, I would think that if a single large-value observation in low likelihood space is throwing off your R_hat (PSRF) that much, then you aren't sampling enough.